# Removing duplicate fields in ID3 tags

Tags: windows, linux, mp3, id3

I have a couple of MP3s that have duplicate fields in their ID3 tags. Let me show you what I mean:

[image: Duplicate fields]

This is causing problems with some media players. Is there a tool that can automatically fix these MP3s in batch? I'd prefer a free Windows or Linux program. I'm not afraid to work on the command line if necessary.

Comment: You did say a couple of mp3's, why not use the "remove" button?

Comment: Perhaps that was a little misleading... I've got about fifty broken MP3s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up deleting the tags and re-adding them using iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they can do it but you can try:

TagScanner:
http://download.cnet.com/TagScanner/3000-2141_4-10056506.html

or

Zortam
http://download.cnet.com/Zortam-MP3-Media-Studio/3000-2141_4-10074058.html

Comment: I've installed TagScanner and I scanned through the description of both products on their own website. Neither supports fixing these tags in batch, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

you can merge or delete multiple id fields with mp3tag:
http://help.mp3tag.de/options_format.html

1. Install mp3tag
2. Open mp3tag
3. Change folder to where your files with the duplicate tags are (including subdirectories is supported). On the main window you won't see these duplicate fields, but right click on a file and select "Extended Tags" to see possible duplicate fields.
4. In the menu bar select "Actions>Actions" (ALT+6)
5. Create a new action group (icon top right)
6. Name the action to whatever you like (i suggest a descriptive name)
7. Add a new action to the action group we just created (again, top icon right)
8. Select "Remove duplicate fields" as an action type. **ATTENTION:** this will remove ALL multiple fields of all tags, so if you want to keep multiple fields for a specific tag type follow the the next substep, otherwise just skip the next step
9. As first action add action type "Merge duplicate fields" and select the field type that you want to keep having multiple fields (and select a separator character that won't be present in your tags), second action type is the "Remove duplicate fields", and at last action you have to split the field that you joined first with "Split field by separator".
10. Press OK
11. Select the action group you just created and click OK to apply the action to all files in the directories you specified.

Comment: Please explain how it works. Right now, your answer looks like it attempts to promote the product. Please improve your answer to fit these guidelines: [How to not be a spammer](http://superuser.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi better now? thx for the input!